# MacOS, Window Runners Autoscaling on GitLab through AWS ECS Fargate

Tags: gitlab, amazon-ecs, gitlab-ci-runner, aws-fargate

I have setup the Gitlab self hosted instance having one runner registered as "linux runner manager" which is running jobs of Gitlab Pipelines on ECS fargate by using docker image as task, after job completed on Gitlab, that container will be destroyed.

I want to achieve Complete Autoscaling setup for runners of Gitlab where I have Linux, Macos & windows runner managers building these 3 different platforms pipelines based on docker containers inside ECS Fargate cluster.

I have achieved this setup in case of linux by following this official [documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/runner_autoscale_aws_fargate/) of Gitlab.

Here is the desired rough diagram of what i have in mind

[image]

In current achieved setup I have these two instances, one gitlab master node and one linux manager instance which is explained in above diagram.

[image]

I have two files on runner manager
one is **config.toml** having connection gitlab and token stuff.
[image]

and the other one is **fargate.toml** having connection ecs fargate.
[image]

Lastly i have cluster ECS cluster having Fargate Arch.

[image]

When the job is being triggered on Gitlab Pipeline, it invoke container in ECS and create new task once job is completed it destroy the task, so in this way ECS cluster will have empty task bucket unless there is triggered pipeline active from gitlab.

[image]

The container image currently which I am using for building jobs on ECS is available [here](https://gitlab.com/aws-fargate-driver-demo/docker-nodejs-gitlab-ci-fargate/-/blob/master/Dockerfile)

I have gone through official documentation of ECS [fargate](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/userguide/what-is-fargate.html) as well
Seems like only window is supported.

***I am wondering if whatever I am looking is even achievable in this case. i.e. is there any official docker files as gitlab runners for windows and macOS is available to support my current architecture? or any customization of files on runner managers end?***

Comment: ECS/Fargate only supports Windows and Linux. There is no MacOS support.

Comment: yes that's what I read also I though maybe is there any workaround possible for this, btw is there any official window images?

Comment: I've never used Windows docker images, but I'd say these look pretty official: https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-windows And no, there is no work-around to get MacOS to run on AWS ECS Fargate. MacOS licensing restrictions prevent Amazon from offering that.